# Book explaining solutions of linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I was reading [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients) article on linear ODE with constant coefficients. However I would like a book reference were all this is well explained. Why the space of solutions of the ODE is of dimension $n$, why exactly are the $C_ie^{p_ix}$ independent, clear explanation on why in case of multiple roots we take also $xe^{qx}, x^2e^{qx},\ldots$ in the basis, why if we have a complex solution we take the real parts. Basically a more detailed version of what is on wikipedia, which proves each fact.

Comment: Any standard ODE textbook should do the job. Perhaps try Edwards, Penney, and Calvis - Differential Equations and Linear Algebra.

Comment: @CheeHan, thank you. The reference was what I needed.